# Append and add event listener

Tags: jquery, events, append

I and having fun with appending elements to the DOM and then added an event listener to the new elements.  I Am using ES6 and Jquery using babel to convert.

```
$('#mainContent')
    .append(`<div id="${divID}" class="row col-md-12"><h3>Click Me</h3></div>`);

$(`#${divID}`)
    .append(moreHTMLtoShowHide);

// Clicky Clicky no working :(
$(`#${divID} h3`).click(() => $(this).next().toggle());
```

The really fun comes when I add the event listener to the console and all is well,  any Ideas?

I also know the append string is not very nice but that is a separate job.

Comment: I also needed to target the element specifically for some reason, there is a change request to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) need to be used for newly added elements.

```
$(document).on('click',`#${divID} h3`,() => $(`#${elmToToggle}`).toggle());
```